# Novel about a ring giving animal powers (climbing/strength) to a girl

Tags: story-identification, books, animals

I'm searching for a book about this girl who had this ring that gave her animal superpowers, pretty sure a gecko was one of them, she like climbed into this house. Another one of her abilities was super strength, but she could only do it when she felt she was in danger. She lifted a dumpster.

Near the end of the book, she found out there was this whole secret organization behind it. The book might have the word "wild" in it, but I'm not sure and don't rely on that

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

*[Going Wild](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28217757-going-wild)* by Lisa McCann

[image: Front cover of Going Wild]

> Charlie Wilde knew her life would change forever when her family moved from the city of Chicago to the suburbs of Arizona…and that was before she found the bracelet. After putting it on, she notices odd things start to happen. Suddenly Charlie seems to have the speed of a cheetah and the strength of an elephant—and that’s just the beginning. She would be thrilled about her transformation if she had any idea how to use the device or control her amazing powers. So Charlie is forced to put her trust in new friends to help her uncover the surprising truth behind the mysterious bracelet.

Found with a search for `novel ring girl animal superpowers`